# Multiple delegates for UITableView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoapods

I think it's best to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve with a concrete example:

Let's say I'm making a cocoapod.
I have a table view inside the example project, and I want the **tableview's delegate methods for its scrolling to be called inside my cocoapod**. I know how to pass the tableView into my cocoapod module, but I'm not sure how I can listen to delegate methods inside it, since I want my ViewController in the example app to also be a delegate.

End result is, I want to show a simple view going up and down with the scrollbar on the tableView when it scrolls.

First of all, **which scrollview delegate methods should I use so I can update the y position of my custom view at all times to match the center of the scrollbar's y position**?

Second of all, **how can I listen to them (scrollview/tableview delegate methods) inside my cocoapod module**?

*Note: I'm using Swift 2.2*

Edit: Here's the end product, thanks to your guys' help, in case anyone's interested: https://github.com/xtrinch/MRTableViewCellCountScrollIndicator

Comment: If you just need to listen to the scrollViewDidScroll delegate method, you could instead rely on observing the `UIScrollView.contentOffset` property through KVO

Comment: `Swift2` tag is only aimed for migration problems. This doesn't seem to be the case, so just `swift` tag should be OK.

Comment: Please post code illustrating what you want to do.

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù that sounds very promising, and if I wanted to show my view only when the user is actually scrolling and hide it like the usual scrollbar does when the user isn't scrolling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve both goals by using [Key-Value Observing (KVO)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html), to monitor the `contentOffset` and the `contentSize` of the scroll view independently of the table view delegate.

The `contentOffset` is the amount that the scrollView has scrolled. The `y` value is the amount scrolled in the vertical direction.

The `contentSize` is the total height of all of the table rows.

KVO lets you write code which gets called whenever a property on another object changes. You can use KVO to monitor changes to `contentSize` and `contentOffset`, and update the custom view when those values change.

Here is how you might implement it in your CocoaPod:

```
private var ContentOffsetKVO = 0
private var ContentSizeKVO = 0

public class ScrollController: NSObject {

    public var customView: UIView? {
        didSet {
            updateScrollPosition()
        }
    }

    public var scrollView: UIScrollView? {
        didSet {
            if let view = oldValue {
                removeKVO(view)
            }

            if let view = scrollView {
                addKVO(view)
                updateScrollPosition()
            }
        }
    }

    deinit {
        if let scrollView = scrollView {
            removeKVO(scrollView)
        }
    }

    private func removeKVO(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        scrollView.removeObserver(
            self,
            forKeyPath: "contentSize",
            context: &ContentSizeKVO
        )

        scrollView.removeObserver(
            self,
            forKeyPath: "contentOffset",
            context: &ContentOffsetKVO
        )
    }

    private func addKVO(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        scrollView.addObserver(
            self,
            forKeyPath: "contentSize",
            options: [.Initial, .New],
            context: &ContentSizeKVO
        )

        scrollView.addObserver(
            self,
            forKeyPath: "contentOffset",
            options: [.Initial, .New],
            context: &ContentOffsetKVO
        )
    }

    public override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

        switch keyPath {

        case .Some("contentSize"), .Some("contentOffset"):
            self.updateScrollPosition()

        default:
            super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        }

    }

    private func updateScrollPosition() {

        guard let scrollView = scrollView, let customView = customView else {
            return
        }

        // Update with the new scroll position.

        let viewSize = scrollView.bounds.size.height
        let scrollLimit = scrollView.contentSize.height - viewSize
        let scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let scrollDelta = scrollOffset / scrollLimit

        let trackerFrame = customView.frame
        let trackerTravel = viewSize - trackerFrame.size.height
        let trackerOffset = scrollOffset + (trackerTravel * scrollDelta)

        customView.frame = CGRect(
            origin: CGPoint(
                x: 0,
                y: trackerOffset
            ),
            size: trackerFrame.size
        )

    }
}
```

To use this:

```
let scrollController = ScrollController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // UITableView is a sub-class of UIScrollView so we can assign it directly.
    scrollController.scrollView = tableView

    let customView = UIView(
        frame: CGRect(
            origin: CGPointZero,
            size: CGSize(
                width: 44,
                height: 44
            )
        )
    )
    customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.magentaColor()
    tableView.addSubview(customView)

    scrollController.customView = customView
}
```

Comment: I get an error at this line:         
case (.Some("contentOffset"), let scrollView as? UIScrollView):
"Invalid pattern"

Comment: Otherwise it's perfect! Just what I've been looking for. Thank you very much

Comment: I fixed the error, and updated the example to show how you could position the custom view, by also observing the `contentOffset`.

Comment: I made some corrections to the examples, to run a bit smoother, and to fix a bug in the use case.

Comment: Awesome. Works. I'm experiencing some very jerky scrolling with the customView though. What could be the cause of that? It being a subview of the tableView? Or the observer not being called often enough?

Comment: I saw that too after I posted the code the first time. I have updated the code since then to fine tune it. This particular issue was caused by the `NSOperation` call in `observeValueForKeyPath`.

Comment: Oh sorry didn't notice that part. Thanks!